# PHP print_r not returning json request

Tags: php, json

The following code runs without any errors, however it doesn't return anything.

If I paste it into my browser it returns the information I'm looking for, I can also replace it with another URL and it works perfectly.

```
$ch = curl_init();

$url = 'https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaName=Somerset&structure={"date":"date","areaName":"areaName","areaCode":"areaCode","newCasesByPublishDate":"newCasesByPublishDate","cumCasesByPublishDate":"cumCasesByPublishDate","newDeathsByDeathDate":"newDeathsByDeathDate","cumDeathsByDeathDate":"cumDeathsByDeathDate"}';
    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);

$decode =json_decode($resp);
print_r($decode);


curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you do json_decode?

Comment: `$decode =json_encode($resp);` needs to be `$decode =json_decode($resp);`

Comment: yes, that was my mistake. I changed it to see if it would make any difference. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');` - for me at least, that URL is returning a gzip-compressed response. Curl won't automatically decompress it unless it's expecting one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following generated code by the postman

```
<?php
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{"date":"date","areaName":"areaName","areaCode":"areaCode","newCasesByPublishDate":"newCasesByPublishDate","cumCasesByPublishDate":"cumCasesByPublishDate","newDeathsByDeathDate":"newDeathsByDeathDate","cumDeathsByDeathDate":"cumDeathsByDeathDate"}',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json'
      ),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is worked. Reason is encoding of received content.

```
try {
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Check if initialization had gone wrong*
    if ( $ch === false ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( 'failed to initialize' );
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,
        'https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaName=Somerset&structure={"date":"date","areaName":"areaName","areaCode":"areaCode","newCasesByPublishDate":"newCasesByPublishDate","cumCasesByPublishDate":"cumCasesByPublishDate","newDeathsByDeathDate":"newDeathsByDeathDate","cumDeathsByDeathDate":"cumDeathsByDeathDate"}' );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Solution is here. Response is the compressed content which your curl failed to detect. Empty encoding means to handle any type of encoding. It should solve your issue.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    if ( $content === false ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( curl_error( $ch ), curl_errno( $ch ) );
    }

    /* Process $content here */


    $decode = json_decode( $content );

    var_dump( $decode );

    // Close curl handle
    curl_close( $ch );
} catch ( RuntimeException $e ) {

    trigger_error(
        sprintf(
            'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
            $e->getCode(),
            $e->getMessage()
        ),
        E_USER_ERROR
    );

}
```